# Check is a specific form field is valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, validation

I've been searching for a while now and haven't found a solution yet.

I'm an ASP.NET and MVC4/Razor2 newbie, so I'm mostly editing the default project.

Anyway, my issue is that I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I need to add an `error` CSS class on a `div` if the under-laying field is not valid.

So far I have this:

```
    <div class="control-group error">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label" })
      <div class="controls">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, null, new { @class = "inline-help error" })
      </div>
    </div>
```

What should I do to make Razor insert the `error` class in the first `div` of my snippet when the field is invalid.

**UPDATE:** I found a way to do it, but it doesn't feel right in comparison to the rest of the code. Is there a better way or is it *the* way to do it?

```
<div class="control-group@((!ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField("Password")) ? " error" : "")">
```

Answer (score 9):

Like this:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString AddClassIfPropertyInError<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
        string errorClassName)
    {
        var expressionText = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var fullHtmlFieldName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData
            .TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expressionText);
        var state = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[fullHtmlFieldName];
        if (state == null)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        if (state.Errors.Count == 0)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(errorClassName);
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<div class="control-group @Html.AddClassIfPropertyInError(x => x.Email, "error")">
    <label class="control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email" />
        <span class="help-inline">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I asked this quite a while ago, it was a small project, I moved on since then. Your solution looks nice, I just don't have the time to test it right now, I might do it eventually.

Comment: Thanks, although I used simply htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(expressionText)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what Loki said, I came across to a nice and tidy solution to work with ModelState class and retrieve specific information to implement each validation logic i desired:

Assuming you want to check validation for a class in your model, named "InnerClass", and field "Name" :

```
if (ModelState["InnerClass.Name"].Errors.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var error in ModelState["InnerClass.Name"].Errors)
    {
        message = error.ErrorMessage;
        isValidFlag = false;
    }
}
```

Instead of above condition, you can use this also :

```
ModelState.IsValidField("InnerClass.Name")
```

ModelState class has great ways to retrieve validation information, so by using mentioned ways you can get more from it with a little workaround.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: That was the key: You need to reference the correct `className.fieldName` in the `ModelState.IsValidField(...)` call, otherwise it will return `true` every time, regardless of the validation state.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just check to see if there is a validation message, quick and dirty...

```
<div class="control-group @(Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) != null ? "error" : "")">
```

Comment: I like this, options for if/else as well, if it would work!

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the `IsValidField` method of the `ModelStateDictionary` in the `ViewData` property of the view.

For a model that is not part of a hierarchy, the answer in your update will work.

For a model that is part of a hierarchy, you need to specify the field name in relation to the entire model.

To get the field name of a model property, use the `Html.NameFor(...)` API.

```
ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField( Html.NameFor(m => m.Password).ToString() )
```

Let's take this one step further and extend the `HtmlHelper` with a utility method that will output text when a field is *invalid*

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class GeneralExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString TextForInvalidField<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string text)
        {
            if(htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(htmlHelper.NameFor(expression).ToString()))
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(text);            
        }
    }
}
```

The end result (from your original example) will look like:

```
<div class="control-group @Html.TextForInvalidField(m => m.Password, "error")">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label" })
  <div class="controls">
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, null, new { @class = "inline-help error" })
  </div>
</div>
```